# Вывод текста в файл

Tags: python, django, csv, импорт, views

Что у меня в функции не так?
Я беру csv файл и вывожу определенные значения в текстовом Но при выводе открывается пустой документ. Инфа не записывается

```
def search(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="new22222.txt"'

    with open('showtable/new.csv', 'r+', encoding='windows-1251') as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            lineread = line.split(';')
            for value in lineread:
                if value.find('Контракт') != -1:
                    return(value[0:55])
                if value.find('Тарифний Пакет') != -1:
                    return(value[0:30])
                if value.find('ВАРТІСТЬ ПАКЕТА/ЩОМІСЯЧНА ПЛАТА') != -1:
                    return(value[0:32] + value[40:55])
                if value.find('ПОСЛУГИ, НАДАНІ ЗА МЕЖАМИ ПАКЕТА') != -1:
                    return(value[0:33] + value[36:49])
                if value.find('ПОСЛУГИ МІЖНАРОДНОГО РОУМІНГУ') != -1:
                    return(value[0:30] + value[33:40])

                input_file.write()
                input_file.close()
    return response
```

Я очень прошу прощения что столько непонятных строк в коде Я просто новичок и делала по своему. в общем это views.py на Джанго. Здесь я беру файл showtable/new.csv и с помощью response, а именно строк response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="new22222.txt"'

передаю в файл "new22222.txt" отображенное value, которое хочу записать в этот файл , так как прописала это каждый раз return value. когда я делала это через консоль в пайчарме. Оно мне выводило как надо. А вот при возврате response - С создается нужный файл а именно "new22222.txt" , но то что выводило в консоль, не записывается в файл.Тоесть мне нужна информация прописанная из csv. Прочитать из файла, что отлично просчитывается и отображается у меня в консоли Но записать это в другой файл а именно new22222.txt

Comment: А куда не "записывается инфа"? Покажите оператор записи в тот документ, который при выводе оказывается пустым?  Кроме того, непонятно назначение input_file.write().  Вообще непонятно назначение input_file.close(). А также их место внутри цикла (короче - проверьте отступы)

Comment: Вы что-то странное делаете. Во-первых, у вас во всём этом коде происходит работа только с одним файлом - showtable/new.csv. Никакого текстового файла у вас не обрабатывается в этом коде. Во-вторых, за весь код вы только один раз выполняете запись в файл, но при этом записываете туда ничто. input_file.write()  - вот здесь вы не передали аргумент.

Comment: Да, объясните, что должна делать функция. Принимать/отдавать инфу? Какой файл должен быть прочитан? Какой файл должен быть записан? Зачем столько return ? Зачем оператор with, если потом пишите close() ?